# scrape just what has been added since last scrape

Tags: django, scrapy

I need to crawl a website, which basically has links like this:

```
www.website.com/link/page_1.html
www.website.com/link/page_2.html
www.website.com/link/page_3.html
...
```

The scraped content is going directly into the database through pipelines.

It is easy to tell django something like:

```
if item exists do not insert it, otherwise insert it
```

But is there any way to scrape the rest of the links which have been added since last scrape?

For example, after website.com inserts new items:

```
/link/page_1.html becomes /link/page_2.html
new items populate /link/page_1.html
```

At this point, what do I need to tell scrapy just scrape the new added items since last scrape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest scrapy has support for serializing requests to disk[1], and also there is Rolando's Redis integration[2].

- [1] http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html
- [2] https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis

Comment: dude you saved me! i've read the jobs chapter, but obviously not careful enough! cheers